# Recycler view arrange items by category

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have created a `RecyclerView` with a `GridManagerLayout`.

For simplicity, my cards have 2 dimensions, their ID and their rarity. I would like to have a button which arranges the cards in the grid by either their ID or their rarity. What would be the way I should go about doing this so that I can animate the cards moving to their new positions?

I have tried creating a new `ArrayList` when the button is pressed and then `notifydDatasetChanged()`. The items switch positions fine but there is no animation, i.e. the cards are just repopulated rather than having a "move"
to the new position effect. I guess this is the case since I am defining a new `ArrayList` instead of altering the current list.

I read another post which says I should use `Collections.swap` in order to do this. Not sure if this is what I should pursue.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I have one possible solution for you!

Write this method inside the `RecyclerView` adapter.

```
public void addItemList(List<JobListApi.Job> newlyCreatedList) {
    int lastPosition = this.mainItemList.size();
    this.mainItemList.addAll(newlyCreatedList);
    this.notifyItemRangeInserted(lastPosition, newlyCreatedList.size());
}
```

Now call this method with newly created `ArrayList`.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: i have not tried this but just looking at it, is this adding on top of the previous array? Wouldnt this duplicate the items in my original list?

Comment: @ImranHamid Yes indeed! But you can clear the original one before adding the new list. I was just trying to solve your animation issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I realised that using `notifyItemMoved()` takes care of the position move animation when using `Collections.swap`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue. If anyone needs the answer, please use `notifyItemMoved()` followed by `notifyItemRangeChanged(position,getItemCount)`